# ASP.Net Web API Returning Array Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Pretty new with ASP.Net WEB API. Having some issues with the proper API configuration (and return type) for my API call which calls another ASHX service.

I have the following codes (tested in HomeController just to verify that the service call would work):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://callme/address.ashx");

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    string content;

    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResult[]>(content);

    return this.View();            
}

public class MyResult
{
    public string ClientAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Now, trying to port it over to an ASP.Net WEB API call:

ClientAddressController.cs

```
public class ClientAddressController: ApiController
{
  public async IQueryable<MyResult> GetClientAddress()
  {
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://callme/address.ashx");

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    string content;

    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResult[]>(content);

    // How to return the result object??
  }
}

public class MyResult
{
    public string ClientAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I need some help to properly define the correct parameters for the WEB Api call so that I could return the result object.

The result object would just be an array of strings:

```
[{"Address": "Address 100"}, {"Address": "Address 200"}, {"Address": "300"}]
```

Hoping to get some insights on resolving this. I have some idea with regards to returning database queries in Web API, but the service calls (and the async method) kind of threw me off the groove.

Thanks.

**UPDATE*****

Was able to find some resolution on this and I am posting the solution I have.

```
public class ClientAddressController: ApiController
{
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetClientAddress()
  {
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://callme/address.ashx");

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    string content;

    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResult[]>(content);
    return Ok(result);

    // How to return the result object??
  }
}

public class MyResult
{
    public string ClientAddress { get; set; }
}
```

P.S.: I am going to accept @Stripling's answer as his provided me some direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a class with an `Address` property, and map the results to objects of that class:

```
public async IQueryable<ClientAddressResult> GetClientAddress()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://callme/address.ashx");

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    string content;

    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    IEnumerable<MyResult> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyResult[]>(content);

    return result.Select(r => new ClientAddressResult{Address = r.ClientAddress})
        .AsQueryable();
}
```

DTO Classes:

```
public class MyResult
{
    public string ClientAddress { get; set; }
}

public class ClientAddressResult
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return array values as dynamic List to be able to do that set method return with dynamic List.

```
var resultList = new List<dynamic>();

resultList.Add(new {Address="Address 100"});
resultList.Add(new {Address="Address 200"});
resultList.Add(new {Address="Address 300"}); 

return resultList;
```

Hope this is what you are loooking for.